# AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ListBox'

Tags: python, tkinter

В моменте кода:

```py
self.lbproblems = tk.ListBox(main, width=15, height=8)
self.lbproblems.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Ошибка:

> AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ListBox'

Comment: Я не уверен, но должно быть `tkinter.Listbox`

Comment: @SKIP ```import tkinter as tk``` - в начале кода

Comment: @SKIP смотри на ошибку: там написано ```AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ListBox'```

Comment: Я то посмотрел на ошибку, но вы этого не сделали, ошибка в том, что в `tkinter` нет класса `ListBox`, но есть `Listbox`

Comment: @SKIP напиши это как ответ на вопрос - помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ошибка в том, что в tkinter нет класса `ListBox`, но есть `Listbox`

```py
self.lbproblems = tk.Listbox(main, width=15, height=8)
self.lbproblems.grid(row=0, column=0)
```